# Appropriate delegation of responsibility in the following situation?

Tags: java, tdd, separation-of-concerns

I'm relatively new to TDD design and am working on a project to gain experience with it.  My project is a tower defense style game - I'm starting out with a basic Creep (monster) and designing it based off of tested behavior.  However, how the creep moves is a rather complicated method.  It currently looks something along the lines of:

```
public void moveToward(Point2D destination) {
  if (canMove()) {
    if (speedGreaterThanDistance(destination) {
      leftoverDistance = calculateLevtoverDistance(destination);
      currentLocation.setLocation(destination);
    } else {
      // do math to calculate x distance and y distance to move
      Point2D newLocation = new Point2D.Double(oldX + xTrans, oldY + yTrans);
      currentLocation.setLocation(newLocation);
    }
  }
}
```

This really doesn't feel like the right design and structure, but I'm unsure how to go about segmenting it up.  Does anyone have any suggestions or links to point me to on how to go about doing this?  My design has a Creep object as part of my business logic, so I know it's going to have to be at least somewhat complex, but it just doesn't seem like I have it right at the moment.  Could part of my problem be that I don't have appropriate value objects in place?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a Creep with a CurrentPosition (a Point2D), a Direction (a Vector xTrans, yTrans) and a Destination (a Point2D).

The Creep behavior is, as far as I understand:

- When the Creep cannot move, its CurrentPosition after a turn should remain the same,
- When the Creep can move and the distance between CurrentPosition and Destination is less  than the norm of Direction, the after a turn CurrentPosition should be Destination,
- When the Creep can move and the distance between CurrentPosition and Destination is strictly greater than the norm of Direction, the after a turn CurrentPosition should be CurrentPosition + Direction.

In that perspective, I would tend to extract the calculation/geometry part into a Geometry class, and state the Creep behavior as

```
public void moveToward(Point2D destination) 
{
  if (CanMove()) 
  { 
    var distanceToDestination = Geometry.Distance(CurrentPosition, destination);
    var distancePerTurn = Geometry.Length(Direction);
    if (distanceToDestination <= distancePerTurn)
    {
      CurrentPosition = destination;
    }
    else
    {
      CurrentPosition = Geometry.Add(CurrentPosition, Direction);
    }   
  }
}
```

You can now test the methods on the Geometry class, and the 3 behaviors of the Creep should be testable as well.

Comment: You do understand my problem correctly.  :)  I will consider what you have said and see about implementing it.  If I like it, I'll credit you with the answer.  Until then - hopefully more suggestions will arise.  ^.^  Thank you for the input.  :)

Comment: I've been thinking about this approach.  The way I see your suggestion, I'd refactor out some of the work to a helper class with a bunch of static methods (like Length) to do some of the other work for me.  I'm not sure how this is a benefit over just having private helper methods within my class to do it for me.  Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: I see 2 related arguments here. First, chances are that other elements of your game will use the same type of logic; then, arguably, the position and movement of the creep are its responsibility, but the related computations aren't: the distance to destination doesn't sound like it's the job of the Creep. I would tend to use a static helper for Geometric computations, but you may also end up with a non-static Board class or something like that, which would own positions and handle distances.

Comment: Hmm...  The first argument is a good point.  I will have other objects that will also be moving (namely projectiles).  So having a helper class for handling those calculates would be a good separation.  In terms of the Google Tech Talks that I've been watching, they say that singletons are difficult to test - however, since this would only be a helper class with static methods (not a singleton), it should be simple to TDD, right?